# Set options values to an entity property

Tags: database, entity-framework-core, modeling

I come from [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com), and with Django's ORM when defining a model I can set options, for example:

```
class MyModel(Model):

    CHOICES = (...)   # List of choices here
                      # it has tu be a 2-tuple list
                      # but that's is not the point right now.

    choice = IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)  # Set the choices.
```

Now, when `MyModel` is used to create an instance, the attribute(property) `choice` can hold only values defined in `CHOICES`.

There is some like this for **EntityFrameworkCore-2.0**?

It is something like this possible?

```
class MyEntity
{
   [choices=EnumDefiningChoices] 
   property enum choices { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A property can have a single defined value, an `int`, `string`, etc in order to be stored in a database.

An approach is to use 2 tables, one for your entity and one for the choices.

**MyEntity:**

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // all the other properties

    public int ChoiceId { get; set; } // Here is the refference for the choice
    public virtual Choice Choice { get; set; }
}
```

**Choice:**

```
public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the `ChoiceId` will allow only values from the `Choice` table.

However if you want to use an `Enum` there is no "blocking" mechanism using EF, this must be implemented at the application level.

Comment: This, yes, solve the issue, but I was thinking on a solution in which the ORM will take care of those things for me. I found it, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Indeed, there is a way!

With EF > 6 you can do something like this:

```
public enum Option 
{
    option_1 = 1,
    option_2,
    option_3    
}

class SomeEntity
{
    public Option Option { get; set; }
}
```

And you can get the enum option name with:

```
var option_name = Option.GetName(typeof(Option), some_entity.option_2);
Console.WriteLine(option_name);
```

**References**

[Working with Enumerated Values in Entity Framework](http://var%20option_name%20=%20Option.GetName(typeof(Option),%20Option.option2);%20Console.WriteLine(option_name);)

[Enum.GetName Method (Type, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Notice that this is not exactly the same as Cristian's answer. You could put 200 there and the database **and** the application would be happy, when you know that value isn't valid at all. Instead, if you create a table and use a FK, you know that the value **must** be valid

Comment: You're also limited to using the enum display names, which mean any refactoring could break your storage unintentionally. And you're unable to add layers of metadata, such as friendly names for selection boxes, descriptions of the options, multiple sort orders, etc.